# Android NDK project adding another "lib" to my .so file

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use a C++ function (that is referenced using a .so file) from my C JNI code. To illustrate my project architecture, it looks like this:

> Java -> C (JNI) -> C++ function

This is what my Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# My C++ library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../../../../module_service/lib/system/lib/libmodule_service.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# JNI C code
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../../../../../module_service/src
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := my_module

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Using "ndk-build" command, my project builds. But when I try to run it on my device, it crashes with the following message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sampleapp.mysampleapplication-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblibmodule_service.so"
```

What is adding another "lib" to my .so file? If I create another .so file named "liblibmodule_service.so" (in addition to "libmodule_service.so") in my /system/lib directory, it works. But that feels like a hacky solution, and I would prefer to not have both "libmodule_service.so" AND "liblibmodule_service.so" which are the same exact files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should post the code how you load the libmodule_service library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may be using `System.loadLibrary("libmodule_service");` to load the library, change it to `System.loadLibrary("module_service");`

Comment: Thank you! I definitely did have that, doh! You just made my day